# Why TTR::SMA returns NA for first element of series when n=1?

Tags: r, moving-average

This is what I am looking at:

```
library(TTR)
test <- c(1:10)
test <- SMA(test, n=1)
test
 [1] NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

The reason I am asking is actually that I have a script that let you define n:

```
library(TTR)
test <- c(1:10)
Index_Transformation <- 1 #1 means no transformation to the series
test <- SMA(test, n = Index_Transformation)
test
 [1] NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Is there any way I can have the SMA function return the first element of the series when "n =1" instead of NA?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollmean` instead from `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
rollmean(test, 1)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  8  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Just out of curiosity I was studying `SMA` function , it calls `runMean` function internally. So if you do

```
runMean(test, 1)
# [1] NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

it still gives the same output.

Further, `runMean` calls `runSum` in this way

```
runSum(x, n)/n
```

So if you now do

```
runSum(test, 1)
#[1] NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

there is still `NA`. Now `runSum` is a very big function from where the original `NA` is generated.

So if in case you still have to persist in using `SMA` function can you add an additional `if` check saying

```
if (Index_Transformation > 1) # OR (Index_Transformation != 1)
   test <- SMA(test, n = Index_Transformation)
```

So `test` only changes if `Index_Transformation` is greater than 1 and stays as it is if it is 1.